# cakephp 3 undefined property cookie component unit test

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cookies, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I tried to test my component function through unit testing.
My component function below

```
public function userRole() { 

    $loginId = $this->Cookie->read('Admin.login_id');
    $name = $this->Cookie->read('Admin.name'); 
    $role = $this->Cookie->read('Admin.role'); 
    if (empty($loginId) || empty($name)){ 
        return false; 
    }

    $adminsORM = TableRegistry::get('Admins');
    $admin = $adminsORM->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['login_id' => $loginId, 'name' => $name, 'disable' => 0]
    ])->first(); 



    return empty($admin)? false : $admin->role; 
}
```

And my component testing function below

```
public $Acl;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $registry = new ComponentRegistry();
    $this ->Acl = new AclComponent($registry);
}

public function testUserRole()
{
    // Test our adjust method with different parameter settings       
        $this->Cookie->write('Admin.login_id', 'demo12');
        $this->Cookie->write('Admin.role', 1);        
        $this->Cookie->write('Admin.name', 'demo 12');   
    $output = $this->Acl->userRole();
    $this->assertResponseOk();

}
```

composer testing code

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testUserRole /d/xampp/htdocs/admin/admin/tests/TestCase/Controller/Component/AclComponentTest.php
```

error

> Notice Error: Undefined property: App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Component\AclComponentTest::$Cookie in [D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\admin\tests\TestCase\Controller\Component\AclComponentTest.php, line 31]

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), and please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks!

Comment: @ndm thanks for comment. i already posted my cakephp version 3.5 here u can see command line and error also.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, there is no `$this->Cookie` property in your unit test. I can only assume that `$this->Cookie` in your component refers to the Cookie component (which btw is deprecated as of CakePHP 3.5).

If you need to prepare cookies for a regular unit test, and not a controller/integration test (where you could to use the `IntegrationTestCase::cookie()`, `IntegrationTestCase::cookieEncrypted()`, `IntegrationTestCase::assertResponseOk()` methods), then you have to write the cookies directly to the request object, and make sure that you make it available to the component.

Check out the example in the Cookbook on how to test components, it should look something like this:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Component;

use App\Controller\Component\MyComponent;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

class MyComponentTest extends TestCase
{
    public $component = null;
    public $controller = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $request = new ServerRequest();
        $response = new Response();

        $this->controller = $this->getMockBuilder('Cake\Controller\Controller')
            ->setConstructorArgs([$request, $response])
            ->setMethods(null)
            ->getMock();

        $registry = new ComponentRegistry($this->controller);
        $this->component = new MyComponent($registry);
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can then either define the cookies in the `setUp()` method, so that they are available in all tests, or you can define them individually per test. Also note that if you're working with encrypted cookies, you should use `CookieCryptTrait::_encrypt()` to encrypt the cookie data.

```
// ...
use Cake\Utility\CookieCryptTrait;
use Cake\Utility\Security;

protected function _getCookieEncryptionKey()
{
    // the cookie component uses the salt by default
    return Security::getSalt();
}

public function testUserRole()
{
    $data = [
        'login_id' => 'demo12',
        'role' => 1,
        'name' => 'demo 12'
    ];
    // the cookie component uses `aes` by default
    $cookie = $this->_encrypt($data, 'aes');

    $request = new ServerRequest([
        'cookies' => [
            'Admin' => $cookie
        ]
    ]);
    $this->controller->request = $request;

    $output = $this->Acl->userRole();
    $this->assertEquals('expected value', $output);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Testing > Testing Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-components)**
- **[API > \Cake\Utility\CookieCryptTrait](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Utility.CookieCryptTrait.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [testing documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-with-encrypted-cookies), in order to set your cookies during your test cases, you need to use the function `$this->cookieEncrypted('my_cookie', 'Some secret values')`:

```
$this->cookieEncrypted('Admin.login_id', 'demo12');
$this->cookieEncrypted('Admin.role', 1);        
$this->cookieEncrypted('Admin.name', 'demo 12');
```

Comment: I tried with ur suggestion. It's displaying same error. I think during unit test for component it was unable to get another component like "Cookie" I tried with public $components = array('Cookie'); $this->Cookie->write('Admin.login_id','demo12');  Same error.

Comment: If you're using Cakephp 3, you need to load a component like this `$this->loadComponent('Cookie');` in the function `setUp()`

Comment: `cookieEncrypted()` would only work in an integration test, a component test however is (or at least should be) a regular unit test, so the request and its cookies must be set up (more or less) manually and made available to the component.